Unable to request custom scope in Azure B2C tenant when integrating with API from main Azure tenant
I’ve been struggling with an issue regarding integrating Azure B2C with an API from my main Azure tenant. Here's the scenario:
Setup:

Main Tenant (TMain): This is my main Azure tenant.
B2C Tenant (TB2C): Created by associating it with TMain's
subscription.
In TMain, I have:

A frontend app registration.
A backend API registration.
The backend API exposes one custom scope and one custom role.
The frontend app has permissions for both the custom scope and role.


In TB2C, I created another app registration for a frontend app (B2CFE).
Using az ad sp create --id some-custom-id-guid, I created an Enterprise Application in TB2C, which seems to have imported my API from TMain into TB2C.
I assigned the necessary permissions and roles to B2CFE from the newly created Enterprise Application.
I configured user flows in TB2C to allow Microsoft Account login.

Now, the problem is:
Given my preliminary testing using very simple code:
class Program
{
    // Replace these values with your own
    private const string ClientId = "TB2C-new-app-client-id";
    private const string TenantName = "TB2C-Name";
    private const string TenantId = "TB2C-ID";
    private const string Authority = $"https://>TenantName <.b2clogin.com/tfp/>TenantName <.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_main";
    private static readonly string[] Scopes = { "api://scope-from-enterpise-app-in-B2C/api.read" };

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the MSAL confidential client application
            var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(ClientId)
                .WithAuthority(Authority)
                .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
                .Build();

            // Acquire a token interactively
            var result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();

            // Display the access token
            Console.WriteLine("Access Token:");
            Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Display the ID token
            Console.WriteLine("ID Token:");
            Console.WriteLine(result.IdToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

I’m unable to request the custom scope while logged in with a global admin user from TMain.
The error message I receive is:
AADB2C90117: The scope 'api://scope-from-enterprise-app-in-B2C/api.read' provided in the request is not supported.
Desired Solutions:
I’m aiming for one of the following architectures:
Option A:
A single frontend and backend app, where both internal and B2C users can authenticate, with different backend scopes for each type of user.

Option B:
Two separate frontend apps connected to the same backend API, with each frontend app using different sets of permissions/scopes.

In both solutions, I would need:
User impersonation.
Application-level permissions for the API.
Role-based authorization (roles must be included in the tokens from both providers).

Questions:
Why am I unable to request the custom scope in TB2C when logging in with a user from TMain?
How can I set up either of the desired architectures while ensuring the correct permissions, roles, and user impersonation are in place?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

AFAIK the scope api://xx/scopename does not work with authority https://>TenantName <.b2clogin.com/tfp/>TenantName <.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_main as it a Azure AD scope hence to make it work change authority as https://login.microsoftonline.com/B2CtenantID

When I changed the authority as the https://login.microsoftonline.com/B2CtenantID it worked successfully check this signed in with B2C tenant user

Unfortunately it does not work, but changes the error I'm getting to AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://>B2CTRenantName<.onmicrosoft.com/>B2CEnterpriseAppId< was not found in the tenant named >B2CTenantId<. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
Enterprise app exists on B2C, scopes and permissions are added to B2C Client App and are confirmed. Redirect is set to address set in Single-page application.

Try changing the authority to https://login.microsoftonline.com/B2CtenantID

What is the authority you passed?

https://login.microsoftonline.com/>Id-of-the-B2C-Tenant<
Said error popped up after this change.

Can I post an answer with details of how to pass https://login.microsoftonline.com/B2CtenantID and the setup?

Yes, off course

Created a Backend app in Azure AD tenant AADBackEnd and added custom role and scope:


And created a Frontend application in Azure AD Tenant AADFrontEnd and granted API permissions like below:

Create an Enterprise application instance of Backend app AADBackEnd in Azure AD B2C tenant:
az login --tenant <B2CTenantID> --allow-no-subscriptions

az ad sp create --id <AADBackEndAppID>


Now I used the below authorize endpoint to authorize the AADFrontEnd app in Azure B2C tenant:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=AADFrontEndAppID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=RedirectURL
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://AADBackEndAppID/.default
&state=12345

And sign in with Azure B2C tenant admin user and click on Accept:

In Enterprise application of Azure AD B2C, both applications AADBackEnd and AADFrontEnd are present:

Make sure AADFrontEnd in Azure AD B2C tenant has permissions granted:

I created a test application in Azure AD B2C tenant B2CFE and granted API permissions:

And got the same error when tried the same code as you:

To resolve the error, the scope api://xx/scopename does not work with authority https://<TenantName>.b2clogin.com/tfp/<TenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_main as it an Azure AD scope hence to make it work change authority as https://login.microsoftonline.com/B2CtenantID
Note that AcquireTokenInteractive only works with public client application that is the redirect URL must be registered as Mobile and desktop applications and set Allow public client flows as YES:

Assign the role in the Azure AD B2C tenant AADBackEnd app to the user:

Modify the authority like below and login with B2C user:
class Program
{
    private const string ClientId = "B2CFEClientID";
    private const string TenantName = "Tenantname";
    private const string TenantId = "B2CTenantID";
    private const string Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}";
    private static readonly string[] Scopes = { "api://***/api.read" };

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(ClientId)
                .WithAuthority(Authority)
                .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
                .Build();
            var result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Access Token:");
            Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("ID Token:");
            Console.WriteLine(result.IdToken);
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"User interaction required: {ex.Message}");
        }
        catch (MsalException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MSAL error: {ex.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An unexpected error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

Tokens generated successfully:

When decoded roles and scp claim is displayed:


Thank you for such extensive answer, amazing job! Given your knowledge of this topic I have couple of questions. If possible, you could extend your answer or maybe add another one. 1: If I would like to test the actual MSAL flow, do you have a sample for react plus dotnet api?
2: If so, what are the changes required?
3: I noticed that after logging in there are no role claims in access token - how so (I am logging in as user from main tenant with custom API role assigned )?
4: What is the correct way to let's say call GRAPH api from this custom api on behalf of user when using B2C fe APP?

Also, given change to Audience - will typical user still follow the custom user flow which is required?

No by changing the audience the user will not follow custom user flow

And regarding your first question to doing in react please post a new question

Let me know if the posted answer works for you

The role must be assigned in the B2C tenant not in aad tenant

About audience - how can we make this work with the b2c flow - that's the whole reason for new tenant - to be able to use single backend api with both internal and external users, where external users are registered / logged-in using B2C flow? You mentioned that api://xx/scopename format does not work with B2C audience - is there an alternative format available to introduce?

No for the scope api://**/scope you cannot use b2c aud

I understand that for such scope I cannot use B2C aud - what would be the usable scope format then?

In b2c app you need to expose an api and add scope which is in this format https://b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/scopename

I changed Application ID URI of the main tenant API to https://>main_tenant_name<.onmicrosoft.com/testapi. This cause exposed scopes to be in your desired format (at least I think so). I switched back the Authority to previous one and requested scope in new format. Now the access token is missing....
I tried it with both the delegated permission and application permission.

Is it not possible to get the access token with scopes from main tenant's api application using FE client app registration in B2C using custom user flow?

Yes AFAIK it is not possible

For no no - problem remains but given your statement - it is unfortunately unsolvable
